# how to update an element of a specific div?

Tags: javascript, html, append, updates

I am creating a web page where the user can select an item and the information is displayed. I have two buttons (btnBuy0 and btnBuy1). When BtnBuy0 is clicked, the details of the items showing quantity of 1 is displayed. Again, if btnBuy1 is clicked, the details of that item should be appended below details of item0 but I can't get that to work. Instead the details of item0 is replaced by details of item1.

```
$("#btnBuy0").click(function() {
    if (!sessionStorage['quantity0']) {
        sessionStorage['quantity0'] = 1;
        $("#dropbox").append('<div id = "0"><img class = "thumb" id = "t0" src="../images/21_metoyou.jpg" />'+ teddy[0].desc + ", Price £"
        + teddy[0].price + ", Quantity: " + sessionStorage.getItem('quantity0') + "<button id = 'btnRemove0'>Remove</button></div><br/>");
        updateBasket();
        sessionStorage["total0"] = parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem('quantity0')) * teddy[0].price;
        updateSubtotal();
    } else {
        sessionStorage['quantity0']++;
        $("#dropbox").html('<div id = "0"><img class = "thumb"  id = "t0" src="../images/21_metoyou.jpg" />' + teddy[0].desc + ", Price £"
        + teddy[0].price + ", Quantity: " + sessionStorage.getItem('quantity0') + "<button id = 'btnRemove0'>Remove</button></div><br/>");
        updateBasket();
        sessionStorage["total0"] = parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem('quantity0')) * teddy[0].price;
        updateSubtotal();

    }

    if (Modernizr.sessionstorage) {  // check if the browser supports sessionStorage
        myids.push(teddy[0].partnum); // add the current username to the myids array
        sessionStorage["ids"]=JSON.stringify(myids); // convert it to a string and put into sessionStorage
    } else {
     // use cookies instead of sessionStorage
    }
});

$("#btnBuy1").click(function() {
    if (!sessionStorage['quantity1']) {
        sessionStorage['quantity1']=1;
        $("#dropbox").append('<div id = "1"><img class = "thumb" id = "t1" src="../images/birthday_metoyou.jpg" />' + teddy[1].desc + ", Price £"
         + teddy[1].price + ", Quantity: " + sessionStorage.getItem('quantity1') + "<button id = 'btnRemove1'>Remove</button></div><br/>");
         updateBasket();
        sessionStorage["total1"] = parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem('quantity1')) * teddy[1].price;
        updateSubtotal();
    } else {
        sessionStorage['quantity1']++;
        $("#dropbox").html('<div id = "1"><img class = "thumb" id = "t1" src="../images/birthday_metoyou.jpg" />' + teddy[1].desc + ", Price £"
         + teddy[1].price + ", Quantity: " + sessionStorage.getItem('quantity1') + "<button id = 'btnRemove1'>Remove</button></div><br/>");
         updateBasket();
        sessionStorage["total1"] = parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem('quantity1')) * teddy[1].price;
        updateSubtotal();
    }

    if (Modernizr.sessionstorage) {  // check if the browser supports sessionStorage
        myids.push(teddy[1].partnum); // add the current username to the myids array
        sessionStorage["ids"]=JSON.stringify(myids); // convert it to a string and put into sessionStorage
    } else {
     // use cookies instead of sessionStorage
    }                
});
```

Comment: Is this more jQuery and/or Modernizer specific?

Comment: This is quite confusing. From your description, I would say that you need to use `$("#dropbox").html()` in the `$("#btnBuy0").click()` function and `$("#dropbox").append()` in the `$("#btnBuy1").click()` one. Can you show some HTML too?

Answer (score 0):

Your code repeats itself almost exactly in the both cases. You should write it once, put it a named function, passing in 1 or 0 depending on the clicked button, and use a variable inside to work out all the code. Something like this:

```
function clicked(whichOne) {
    yolo = 'quantity' + whichOne; //Here I just declare your most used variable to make the code easier to read.

    if(!sessionStorage[yolo]) {
        sessionStorage[yolo] = 1;
    } else {
        sessionStorage[yolo]++;
    }

    //Notice that using .html() will always replace what's inside the #dropbox.
    //If you want to add to what is already inside, use .append() instead.
    $("#dropbox").html('<div id ="'+ whichOne +'"><img class = "thumb" id = "t' + whichOne +'" src="../images/21_metoyou.jpg" />'+ teddy[whichOne].desc + ", Price £" + teddy[whichOne].price + ", Quantity: " + sessionStorage.getItem(yolo) + "<button id = 'btnRemove"+ whichOne +"'>Remove</button></div><br/>");

    updateBasket();

    sessionStorage["total" + whichOne] = parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem(yolo)) * teddy[whichOne].price;

    updateSubtotal();
}

$("#btnBuy0").click(function() {
    clicked(0);
});

$("#btnBuy1").click(function() {
    clicked(1);
});
```

You could probably reduce this even more. This is just an example and you'll need to adapt it to fit your situation.
Btw here's a fiddle you can play around with to get a better idea: http://jsfiddle.net/ArzSs/2/

Comment: didnt notice i had repetition of code. thanks for pointing that out